# How can I query the API from Marketstack

Tags: c#

I want to program a graphical user interface in the programming language csharp to show the results of the Marketstack API.

I have tried to find a help for this on a search at Google, but the results did not helping me to solve my problem.

Therefore I decided to place my question here. I hope, that someone on this website can help me on solving my problem.

The necessary data are already available.

And my question is, how can I query the API from Marketstack to get all the information, which I need.

I think, I must used a loop to get the data from the previous days.

Comment: Many people here would be willing to help, but nobody will do it for you. Please try it yourself first and return with any specific programming-related problems you may encounter. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) whenever you ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you with the following:

1. Take a look at the API documentation on [Marketstack's website](https://marketstack.com/documentation).
2. Make sure you have all requirements, like a valid API Key
3. Look for sample codes like in this [Github repository](https://github.com/orshe4/marketstack).

The code below will allow you to query Marketstack. Bear in mind you need a valid API Key or Token to successfully communicate with the API:

**Initialize MarketstackService:**

```
var options = Options.Create(new MarketstackOptions() { ApiToken = "apiToken"});
var marketstackService = new MarketstackService(options, NullLogger<MarketstackService>.Instance);
```

**GetExchanges:**

```
    var exchanges = await marketstackService.GetExchanges();
```

**GetExchangeStocks:**

```
var nasdaqMic = "XNAS";
var stocks = await marketstackService.GetExchangeStocks(nasdaqMic);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the support to solving my problem to access the API of marketstack. But the execute of this code lead to the error code >>401 - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."<<. After replacing the Text "apiToken" with my valid Key, then i get the Message: >>System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)."<<

What can i do, to solve also these problem?

Comment: I want to add, that i am only using the free account of marketstack.

Comment: Forbidden, most certainly means that you're trying to request which you're not authorized to do. Try requesting something you're allowed to with the free account. If not, you'll have to purchase a paid account.